# Existence of infinite non empty intersection of sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be an open bounded set and $U_{k,n} \subset U$ be a collection of sets (can be assumed open or closed) for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\in \{1,\ldots,K\}$. If we have
$$ U = \bigcup_{k\leq K} U_{k,n}, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
is the following true: there exists an infinite subset $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $k_0 \leq K$ such that
$$ \bigcap_{n \in \mathcal{T}} U_{k_0,n} \; \; \text{is of non empty interior}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @GEdgar $U$ is open in a topological compact space of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: @Crostul I could show that there exists $k_0$ such that $\limsup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{k_0,n} \neq \emptyset$. But this is not exactly the same thing, although close. 
To show this, it suffices to notice that $U = \bigcup_{k\leq K} \limsup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_{k,n}$.

Comment: This is true even without the topological conditions. It is a result of the infinite pigeonhole principle. In particular, given any $x\in U,$ you can pick $k_0$ and $\mathcal T$ so the intersection contains $x.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that the intersection should be of non empty interior, not just non empty. The issue is that for each point we have a different $\mathcal{T}$, but can we have a continuous number of points with the same $\mathcal{T}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I did, it should be visible. Please let me know if it's not.

Comment: You didn’t add that $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n.$

Comment: It's optional, I think the fact that it's $\mathbb{R}^d$ wouldn't add much. All that is needed is that it's bounded and open. Added it still! Maybe the finite dimension helps.

Comment: One idea is to write $U = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k\leq K} U_{k,n}$, then push the intersection into the union and write the resulting form. This might be a union of sets including the desired one. As this union is open and bounded, there must exists one set in this union that is open.

Comment: To specify further the above idea, we can write $U = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k\leq K} U_{k,n} = \bigcup_{(k_T)_{T} \in \{1,\ldots,K\}^{\mathbb{N}}}\bigcap_{T\in \mathbb{N}} U_{k_T,T}.$ Does that imply that there exists $(k_T)_T$ for which $\bigcap_{T\in \mathbb{N}} U_{k_T,T}$ is of non empty interior? Maybe by taking the interior of the union? Is so it would end of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U=(0,1)$ and for each $n$ and $k\le K$ make $U_{k,n}$ as follows:
$$
U_{k,n}=\bigcup\Bigl\{\bigl(i\cdot K^{-n},(i+2)\cdot K^{-n}\bigr):0\le i< K^n-1,\ i\equiv k \pmod{K}\Bigr\}
$$
Then $U_{k,n}$ contains no intervals longer than $2K^{-n}$, so set of the form $\bigcap_{n\in T}U_{k_0,n}$ contains non-trivial intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample.

$U = (0,1)$.  $K = 2$.   For $n = 1,2,3,\dots$
let $A_n = \{j/n : 1 < j < n, j \text{ odd}\}$ and
$B_n = \{j/n : 1 < j < n, j \text{ even}\}$.  Define
$$
U_{1,n} = (0,1) \setminus A_n,\qquad U_{2,n} = (0,1) \setminus B_n
$$
Any interval contined in $U_{k,n}$ has length at most $2/n$.
For all $n$ we have $(0,1) = U_{1,n} \cup U_{2,n}$.

Now let $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathbb N$ be infinite, let $k_0 \in \{1,2\}$
and
$$
V = \bigcap_{n \in \mathcal T} U_{k_0,n}.
$$
I claim $V$ has empty interior.  Let $\varepsilon > 0$.  Choose $n_0$
so that $2/n_0 < \varepsilon$.  Then choose $n_1 \in \mathcal T$ so that
$n_1 > n_0$.  This means
$$
V \subseteq U_{k_0,n_1}
$$
so any interval contained in $V$ has length at most $2/n_1 < \varepsilon$.
This is true for every $\varepsilon> 0$.  So
the connected components of $V$ are single points.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, do you think a similar counter example works for higher dimensions? Say  $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d\geq 2$ or $3$. Also if $(U_{k,n})_{k\leq K}$ were disjointed for each $n$?

Comment: Yes in higher dimensions subtract a finite union of hyperplanes, so that the components are cubes with side $2/n$.